# Не передается событие второй кнопке

Tags: javascript, события, click

Вот пример. В HTML документе два input type button. Первая кнопка работает исправно, а второй не удается передать click в качестве аргумента. В чем ошибка ?

```
window.onload = function(){
    var btn1 = document.querySelector('input[name=btn1]');
    var btn2 = document.querySelector('input[name=btn2]');


    function OurJquery(){
        this.btnClick1 = function(elem, fun){
            elem.addEventListener('click', fun);
        }
        this.btnClick2 = function(elem, event, fun){
            elem.addEventListener('event', fun);
        }
    };

    var Click1 = new OurJquery;
    Click1.btnClick1(btn1,function(){console.log('neo')
    });

    var Click2 = new OurJquery;
    Click2.btnClick1(btn2,click, function(){console.log('morf')
    });

}
```

Comment: +1 - все не правильно. С наступающим!

Comment: -1 - выглядит ужасно. С наступающим!

Comment: Может еще html скинешь? С наступающим!

Comment: Ждем весь код. С наступающим!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn1 = document.querySelector('input[name=btn1]');
  var btn2 = document.querySelector('input[name=btn2]');


  function OurJquery() {
    this.btnClick1 = function(elem, fun) {
      elem.addEventListener('click', fun);
    }
    this.btnClick2 = function(elem, event, fun) {
      elem.addEventListener(event, fun);
    }
  };

  var Click1 = new OurJquery;
  Click1.btnClick1(btn1, function() {
    console.log('neo')
  });

  var Click2 = new OurJquery;
  Click2.btnClick2(btn2, "click", function() {
    console.log('morf')
  });

}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button 1"/>
<input type="button" name="btn2" value="Button 2"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это гениальное решение)

Comment: @ВадимФлоров Оно будет выглядеть еще гениальнее, когда слева от него будет гореть знак "галочка", означающий принятый ответ.